# How can i scroll panel with two buttons left and right

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I already try these, but it's not working very well

- For buttons 11-15, only `"<"` appear, since there are no more buttons
  Once » is clicked.
- buttons 6-10 show, with both `<` and `›` visible
- Viewing buttons 1-5: there is only a `›` button

So for example, if there are 15 buttons, and the screen can only show 5 buttons
The `"<"` and `"»"` buttons appear, and when clicked, scroll to either the left or right
it should jump views. For example, pressing it once should show buttons 6-10, then pressing it again shows buttons 11-15
2 clicks needed to see entire 15 buttons

```cs
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // need to disable AutoScroll, otherwise disabling the horizontal scrollbar doesn't work
        Panel.AutoScroll = false;

        // disable horizontal scrollbar
        Panel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
    }

    public int scrollValue = 0;

    public int ScrollValue
    {
        get
        {
            return scrollValue;
        }
        set
        {
            scrollValue = value;

            if (scrollValue < Panel.HorizontalScroll.Minimum)
            {
                scrollValue = Panel.HorizontalScroll.Minimum;
            }

            if (scrollValue > Panel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
            {
                scrollValue = Panel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
            }

            Panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = scrollValue;
            Panel.PerformLayout();
        }
    }

    private void btnleft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollValue -= Panel.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;
    }

    private void btnright_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollValue += Panel.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel.Controls.Add(new Button()
        {
            Width = 67,
            Height = Panel.Height
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s not really clear exactly what your problem is, are you attempting to build your own paging navigation system?  Update your question with a clear explanation of your problem you working on.  And are you looking for c# or vb.net solutions?  If both tags are valid update your question explaining how

Comment: I think the question is simple and exactly what i want "How can i scroll panel with two buttons left and right"

Answer (score 0):

you must to have 2 button left and right

I write for image like this and my code is this :

```
   Pic Image .Image = Image .From File(Image1);
        count = 1;
```

and count ++ when we push those buttons

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).